# Is QPainter supposed to be cached between render calls?

Tags: qt

Looking at the QT code it seems that QPainter is trying to reuse existing QPainter instances via `QWidget::sharedPainter()` (See QPainterPrivate::attachPainterPrivate). For some reason though this sharedPainter() is only set during a single render pass and then reset to null again.

What is the expected lifetime of a QPainter and the associated QPaintEngine? Should it be created once per application lifetime or once per render call?

How about QPaintEngine::begin()? Should it be called for every render pass or once per engine creation?

Looking at code from QGLPaintEngineEx2 it seems that in particular the QPaintEngine::begin() can contain some costly initialization:

```
#if !defined(QT_OPENGL_ES_2)
    QGLExtensionMatcher extensions; // <- calls glGetString for the extension strings
    d->hasCompatibilityExtension = extensions.match("GL_ARB_compatibility");

    bool success = qt_resolve_version_2_0_functions(d->ctx)
                   && qt_resolve_buffer_extensions(d->ctx)
                   && (!QGLFramebufferObject::hasOpenGLFramebufferObjects()
                       || qt_resolve_framebufferobject_extensions(d->ctx));
    Q_ASSERT(success);
    Q_UNUSED(success);
#endif

    d->shaderManager = new QGLEngineShaderManager(d->ctx); // Dirties the shader manager

    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

#if !defined(QT_OPENGL_ES_2)
    glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
#endif

    d->glyphCacheType = QFontEngineGlyphCache::Raster_A8;

#if !defined(QT_OPENGL_ES_2)
#if defined(Q_WS_WIN)
    if (qt_cleartype_enabled
        && (fontSmoothingApproximately(1.0) || fontSmoothingApproximately(2.1)))
#endif
#if defined(Q_WS_MAC)
    if (qt_applefontsmoothing_enabled)
#endif
        d->glyphCacheType = QFontEngineGlyphCache::Raster_RGBMask;
#endif

#if defined(QT_OPENGL_ES_2)
    // OpenGL ES can't switch MSAA off, so if the gl paint device is
    // multisampled, it's always multisampled.
    d->multisamplingAlwaysEnabled = d->device->format().sampleBuffers();
#else
    d->multisamplingAlwaysEnabled = false;
#endif

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `QPainter` should be created at the point of use. You're never supposed to cache them, or to have them persist beyond a paint event! That Qt does it is an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks Kuba. I filed a bug report with QT 4.8.7, because at the moment QT 4.8 does not behave this way https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57880

Comment: "A QPainter should be created at the point of use." - This is not true for `QGraphicsStuff...` thou, there you get a pointer to a pre-existing painter in each item's paint function as a parameter.

Comment: @ddriver Obviously, if a painter has been already created for you, then use it. Otherwise, create your own right there.